# IOT hub not recieving or sending messages

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

Iam trying to make a simple app for my raspberry pi that will send a message to the IOThub and then try to receive a response however nothing is happening.

I copied the connectionstring from the device controller. Ofcource I hidden it for this question.

I see it printing out that the message was succesfully sended to the iothub but when I check the iothub I see 0 received messages.

Iam using the free tier of the iothub is this a limitation?

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private const string DeviceConnectionString = "Hidden";

    private readonly DeviceClient _deviceClient;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString, TransportType.Amqp); //Already tried using different transport types but no succes.
    }

    public async Task SendEvent()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\t{0}> Sending message", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
        var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cloud to device message."));
        await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(commandMessage);
        Debug.WriteLine("Succesfully sended message to IotHub");
    }

    public async Task ReceiveCommands()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\nDevice waiting for commands from IoTHub...\n");

        while (true)
        {
            var receivedMessage = await _deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();

            if (receivedMessage != null)
            {
                var messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
                Debug.WriteLine("\t{0}> Received message: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), messageData);

                var propCount = 0;
                foreach (var prop in receivedMessage.Properties)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("\t\tProperty[{0}> Key={1} : Value={2}", propCount++, prop.Key, prop.Value);
                }

                await _deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                Debug.WriteLine("Finishing recieving message");
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Sending event");
        await SendEvent();
        await ReceiveCommands();
        Debug.WriteLine("Received commands");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the D2C message you sent in the [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#run-the-sample-application)?

Comment: Yes iam getting this: Receiving events...
2017-04-10 20:08:53> Device: [RaspberryPI], Data:[Cloud to device message.]

Comment: Well, what do you mean "I check the iothub I see 0 received messages."? You mean you use `ReceiveCommands()` to receive these D2C messages?

Comment: Yes I want ReceiveCommands to get a message from the iothub. I didn't saw any messages received when I logged in azure and went to the iothub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing to do with free tier of the iothub. There is no such limitation.

You can't receive [Device-To-Cloud(D2C) messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#device-to-cloud-messages) using [DeviceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient?view=azuredevicesclient-1.2.6) that you used in `ReceiveCommands()`. It is by designed. You look like having some misunderstanding of Azure IoT Hub message types and SDKs.

There are two kinds of message types: [Device-To-Cloud(D2C) message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#device-to-cloud-messages) and [Cloud-To-Device(C2D) message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#cloud-to-device-messages).

And two kinds of SDKs: [device SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/device) and [service SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/service).

Device SDK is used to connect to and send D2C messages to Azure IoT Hub.
While service SDK is used to manage and send [C2D messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#cloud-to-device-messages) to devices.

So, if you send C2D messages to device in [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#run-the-sample-application) you will receive these messages in your `ReceiveCommands` method.

If you want to receive D2C message you can utilize Event Hub-compatible endpoint(messages/events). Here is [a console sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#receive-device-to-cloud-messages) you can reference. But this is can't be done in UWP due to [service bus not supported in UWP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/50).